# Flutter & Firebase: type 'Query' is not a subtype of type 'CollectionReference'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore, I have a collection called 'habits', and each document has an array with userIDs. I would like to now get a collection with all habits that contain a specific userID in the array.

This is my code:

```
final CollectionReference habitDataCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('habits').where("habitFollowers", arrayContains: 'userID');
```

Now, I get this error: type 'Query' is not a subtype of type 'CollectionReference'

Do you know what I am doing wrong here?

Many thanks for your help!

Nicolas

PS:

The code then uses a Stream to get the snapshot

```
  Stream<List<HabitData>> get habitData {
    return habitDataCollection.snapshots()
      .map(_habitDataListFromSnapshot);
  }
```

and forms it into a dart object

```
  List<HabitData> _habitDataListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc){
     return HabitData(
       hid: doc.documentID ?? '',
       name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
       description: doc.data['description'] ?? '',
       );
    }).toList();
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change this:

```
final CollectionReference habitDataCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('habits').where("habitFollowers", arrayContains: 'userID');
```

into this:

```
final Query habitDataCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('habits').where("habitFollowers", arrayContains: 'userID');
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! This way would break my stream provider:  Stream<List<HabitData>> get habitData {
    return habitDataCollection.snapshots()
      .map(_habitDataListFromSnapshot);
  } Sorry, just getting into Flutter and trying to understand it.

Comment: what is the problem exactly? habitDataCollection returns a Query then you can call `snapshots()` also https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/query.dart#L27 which will return a Stream of type QuerySnapshot

Comment: I apologise - you were right. I must have had some error that I didn't see. It's working all fine how you described. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Perfect! In my specific use case I can now query subcollections without having to have an parent documentId in a Stream.